# Problema de atualização do $scope com cordova e angularJS

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Olá. Estou desenvolvendo um app utilizando cordova, ionic e angularJS. E estou com um problema na atualização de um input.

Tenho a seguinte função que é executada em um ng-click:

```
$scope.buscarContato = function(){
$scope.phone = [];
$scope.phoneId = 0;
$scope.contact = [];
navigator.contacts.pickContact(function (contact){
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.contact = contact;
  });
  $scope.selecionarPhone(contact.phoneNumbers); 
},function (err){
   console.log('Error: ' + err);
});
};


$scope.selecionarPhone = function(phoneNumbers){
var phones = [];
var phoneId = [];
if(!phoneNumbers) return;
 for(var i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.length; i++){
  phones.push({"text": phoneNumbers[i].value});
  phoneId.push( phoneNumbers[i].id );
}

var options = {
  titleText: "Escolha o número a ser pesquisado",
  buttons: phones,
  cancelText: 'Cancelar',
  cancelOnStateChange: true,
  buttonClicked: function (index) {
    $scope.phone = phones[index].text;
    $scope.phoneId = phoneId[index];
    $scope.contatoExiste = true;
    return true;
  }
};

$ionicActionSheet.show(options);

};
```

No final da execução, eu altero o valor de um input na tela, no

```
$scope.phone = removerMascara(phones[index].text);
```

Input:

```
<input type="tel" placeholder="11999999999" name="phone" data-ng-model="phone" maxlength="15" required>
```

A pesquisa e alteração do input acontece normalmente, mas, se eu altero o input manualmente, não consigo mais altera-lo com os dados da agenda, e sequer a primeira linha da função, aonde zero os dados, funciona.

Como eu deveria manipular este escopo corretamente?

Edit:
O problema foi resolvido colocando o escopo phone sob um parent:
    $scope.data.phone

Alguém sabe explicar porque houve essa diferença?

Comment: Cara pior que tá muito bugado angularJS com Córdova. Estou passando por algumas dificuldades também. Só pra você saber que não está sozinho nessa :)

Comment: Pois é. Fiz alguns testes aqui, deixando o botão exclusivamente com a missão de zerar o input, e nem isso ele fez.